# Implode separate date of birth values from php form

Tags: php, sql, laravel, mutators

Ok i'm out of ideas and have reached the end point in my research.

have a registration form with a birthdate select fields example below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        {!! Form::selectMonth('dob_month', 1, ['class'=> 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        {!! Form::selectRange('dob_date', 1, 31, 1, ['class'=> 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        {!! Form::selectYear('dob_year', 1930, 1997, 1991, ['class'=> 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

of course its in laravel's blade template.

As you can see its 3 separate select forms with dob_month, dob_date and dob_year and the values now onto the mutator thats in the user model

```
private function setDobAttribute($dob){

            $dobString = ['dob_year', 'dob_month', 'dob_date'];

            $this->attributes['dob'] = implode('-', array_values($dobString)); 

        }
```

with `dob` as the sql column name.

**The Issue**

I want to capture `dob_year`, `dob_month`, `dob_date` which would be structured as 1997-12-01 with using `implode('-'array_values($dobString))` which would then be saved to the database.

When I go through the process of signing up a new user I get an error message of Undefined index: dob.

Now I am also getting the feeling that in the mutator function `setDobAttribute($dob)` I am missing something within that function code but can't seem to put my finger on what it is.

Input? suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `implode(... array_values)` is kinda pointless. implode will ALREADY be working on the array's values, so there's no point in building a brand new array of the exact same values that implode would've gotten anyways.

Comment: Use php's date function.

Comment: where in your code do you point "dob" to your server, or anywhere else for that matter?

Comment: You pass in `$dob` to your function, and never use it.

Comment: @MarcB without array_values it would give me an error of array to string conversion. In further investigating the php library implode it only allows 1 glue and 1 variable, so an array loop is needed for implode if you have multiple (more than one in my case 3 values) values from a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_map` may be...

```
private function setDobAttribute($dob){
  $keys = ['dob_year', 'dob_month', 'dob_date'];
  $this->attributes['dob'] = 
    implode('-', array_map(function($key) use($dob){
      return $dob[$key];
    }, $keys)); 
  return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private function setDobAttribute(){

    $array = array('dob_year', 'dob_month', 'dob_date');
    return $this->attributes['dob'] = implode(-', $array);
}
```